# How to number subsections continuously within a chapter?

Tags: numbering

How to fix numbering?

Here is a minimal example. I think the problem is self-explanatory.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\thechapter}% <search>
  {\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\else\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 
  0\fi\fi\thechapter}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\@arabic\c@chapter.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1.3}

\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{Appendix C}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection C.1}

\end{document}
```

Just in case: "Subsection 1.3" should be numbered 1.3, and "Subsection C.1" should be numbered C.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems slightly strange numbering scheme but I added subsection to chapter's reset list and removed it from section's.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox,remreset}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\thechapter}% <search>
  {\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\else\ifnum\value{chapter}<10 
  0\fi\fi\thechapter}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\@addtoreset{subsection}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thechapter.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}
\subsection{Subsection 1.2}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1.3}

\appendix
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{Appendix C}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{Subsection C.1}

\end{document}
```